# Dependency Injection resolution with constructors having multiple parameters whose values are determined at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

As a reply to an earlier question ([Accessing ILogger from non-Controller classes in Class Libary .NET Core 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59711887/accessing-ilogger-from-non-controller-classes-in-class-libary-net-core-3)), we can inject the dependent class into the controller. The DI Container resolves dependencies on registration of Transient services at the time of Startup. Hence if a ClassA is instantiated by a Controller, as a result of this mechanism, we can access ILogger in Class A.

Original question code sample:

```
public class Startup
{
    ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {      
        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddTransient<ClassX>();

        ...
    }
}

public class ControllerB : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ClassX classX;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public ControllerB(ClassX classX, ILogger<ControllerB> logger)
    {
        this.classX = classX;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    ...
}

public class ClassX
{
   private readonly ILogger logger;

   public ClassX(ILogger<ClassX> logger)
   {
       this.logger = logger;
   }
}
```

Now I have a scenario as below, where the constructor of `ClassX` has multiple parameters:

```
public class ClassX
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private int _num1;

    public ClassX(ILogger<ClassX> logger, int num1)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.num1 = num1;
    }
}
```

Constructor of `ClassX` made available to .NET Core DI container through `[ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor]`:

```
[ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor]
public ClassX(int num)
{
    this.constructorNum = num;
}
```

So we need to inject the constructor parameters during DI resolution at Startup. I tried this

```
services.AddTransient<Func<int, ClassX>>((provider) =>
{
    return new Func<int, ClassX>((numParam) => new ClassX(numParam));
});
```

But this throws an error as we are not passing the ILogger.

How do I inject the ILogger as well as the constructor parameters at runtime through DI?

Comment: Also you don't have to always use `DI` It's fine if you create a new instance.

Comment: A general rule of thumb - don't use DI if some / all of the parameters you plan to inject are basic types (`int`, `string` etc). I am not saying it _can't_ be done - but if you are reasonably new to DI then it is a pattern I'd suggest avoiding.

Answer (score 12):

For this scenario, you can use the `provider` parameter that's being passed into the factory function to resolve an instance of `ILogger<ClassX>` from the IoC container:

```
services.AddTransient<Func<int, ClassX>>((provider) =>
{
    return new Func<int, ClassX>((numParam) =>
        new ClassX(provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<ClassX>>(), numParam));
});
```

`provider` here is an implementation of `IServiceProvider`. This example uses an extension method, [`GetRequiredService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getrequiredservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceProviderServiceExtensions_GetRequiredService__1_System_IServiceProvider_), to retrieve an instance of `ILogger<ClassX>`.

Comment: BTW by using this method, OP can remove the `ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor` attribute and related constructor.

Comment: You might want to use [`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ClassX>(provider, numParam)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) there to avoid having to list all the injected arguments manually.